# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException in javaFx

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, javafx-2

I am getting java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException in my code 
My code is:-

```
private Stage primaryStage;
    private BorderPane rootLayout;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("BUildsApp");

        initRootLayout();

    }

    public void initRootLayout() {
        try {
            // Load root layout from fxml file.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/BuildsView.fxml"));
            rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

            // Show the scene containing the root layout.
            Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The exception which I am getting is:-

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2434)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
    at ch.main.Buildsapp.MainApp.initRootLayout(MainApp.java:31)
    at ch.main.Buildsapp.MainApp.start(MainApp.java:22)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application ch.main.Buildsapp.MainApp
```

My fxml file is:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <ScrollPane layoutX="178.0" layoutY="68.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <content>
            <TableView prefHeight="350.0" prefWidth="590.0">
              <columns>
                  <TableColumn prefWidth="130.0" text="Release" />
                <TableColumn prefWidth="130.0" text="Date" />
                <TableColumn prefWidth="330.0" text="Builds" />
              </columns>
            </TableView>
         </content>
      </ScrollPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I tried few problem links on the same problem from stack overflow but it didn't worked for me.
I am using eclipse 4.5.1.

Comment: Is `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set` meaningful to you?

Comment: sorry, I didn't get you. can you explain what are you trying to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

place the .fxml file in the same package with the class that launches it and set the path like this ("BuildsView.fxml") and it should work fine.

Comment: I was trying to keep the .fxml files and .java file in different folders can't we do that ??

Comment: it should be located in your package its more convenient for you!

Comment: FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("try to put the relative path "));                   go the file right click on it and copy qualified name and then try it   ( but i suggest you to put it in the same package.)